# Struts + GAE java.security.AccessControlException: access denied of struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2

I am using struts in GAE. I am using GAE 1.8 and struts 2.3.15 jar file.

In my application i am facing this exception

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "jar:file:\E:\eclipse\Shaun\Convergent\war\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:431)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:205)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.JarEntryRevision.needsReloading(JarEntryRevision.java:76)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.fileNeedsReloading(DefaultFileManager.java:66)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:394)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:169)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.needReloadContainerProviders(ConfigurationManager.java:215)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalReload(ConfigurationManager.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:968)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.createActionContext(PrepareOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:86)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.convergent.auth.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:32)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.convergent.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I did lot of search some says remove this property value from sturts.xml file

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

Some says change the value from true to false. I did it but it didn't work. Please give a solution. I also change the jar file and use 2.1.8 version but in this i got the exception at startup of server which is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider;)V
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_DefaultProperties(Dispatcher.java:310)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener.contextInitialized(StrutsListener.java:45)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:306)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:254)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:212)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:210)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:210)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
```

I am also using following jar files with struts jar file

```
ognl-3.0.6.jar
sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
struts2-sitemesh-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar
xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar
```

please guide me.

Comment: You should not mix the versions jars from different releases. It only leads to crash.

Comment: so how i resolve my issue?

Comment: Post the code were you using `DevAppServerFactory`

Comment: I am not using DevAppServerFactory. Infact I don't know what is DevAppServerFactory

Comment: If it's maven, post your POM

Comment: No I am using eclipse.

Comment: The problem only occurs on GAE for Windows and it has nothing to do with different jar versions. Check my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my investigation the

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "jar:file:\E:\eclipse\Shaun\Convergent\war\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar"
>   "read")

exception ***only*** occurs when trying to run a Struts 2 application on Google App Engine for **Windows**.

I've encountered the same problem on Windows while trying to port an application to GAE, but I couldn't reproduce it under GNU/Linux nor when deployed to Google servers with appcfg.sh --oauth2 update dist/myapp

In order to solve this problem when running under Google App Engine for Windows **the only working solution I found was to implement a [custom plugin / extension point](https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/plugins.html) that implements the following interfaces [com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManager](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/class-use/FileManager.html) and [com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/FileManagerFactory.html)**

The classes which implement the above interfaces inside the plugin override the implementations that Struts 2 instantiates by default, i.e. [DefaultFileManager](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/fs/DefaultFileManager.html) and [DefaultFileManagerFactory](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/fs/DefaultFileManagerFactory.html)

The [custom file plugin](https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/tree/master/custom_file_plugin) I've created has three main components:

1. The [struts-plugin.xml](https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/blob/master/custom_file_plugin/struts-plugin.xml) file specifies that the FileManager and FileManagerFactory implementation from the plugin should be taken as the default
2. [Struts2FileManagerFactoryOnGAE](https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/blob/master/custom_file_plugin/src/org/apache/struts2/customfile/Struts2FileManagerFactoryOnGAE.java), custom implemention of the FileManagerFactory interface where the only change from the DefaultFileManagerFactory implementation is the class name
3. [Struts2FileManagerOnGAE](https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/blob/master/custom_file_plugin/src/org/apache/struts2/customfile/Struts2FileManagerOnGAE.java), custom FileManager implementation, where I've made the essential changes, that is, **fileNeedsReloading() methods and internal should return false, and support() method should return true.**

Also, inside the [WEB-INF/web.xml](https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/blob/master/src/WEB-INF/web.xml) of the application I've added:
`<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>`

Because I use Ant as a build system, I've created new targets for the custom file plugin, that compile & copy the jar of the plugin to the final artifact: https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/blob/master/build.xml

You can see the source code for my test application at: https://gitlab.com/alibitek-java/Struts-GAE/tree/master

and if you want to give it a try you can just run:

> ant dev_appserver

after setting the path to your Google App Engine SDK inside build.xml
or you can see it live here http://struts-gae.appspot.com/jsp/index.jsp

What the application does is: you need to guess the random number that was generated, and after a few tries it will show you a hint, and when you guess the number it will show you in how many tries you've guessed it.

Comment: Thanks Alex you are right this problem only occur on window OS.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `<JRE location>\lib\security\java.policy` file, then add the permission you need inside a  **grant entry** :

```
 permission java.io.FilePermission "E:/eclipse/Shaun/Convergent/-" , "read"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just For Information purpose I Used the following struts2 and x-work jar files and it solved my issue.

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.2.1
- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.2.1

and add this line in struts.xml file

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```